# How do I say: "show me promising"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to email my friend to tell her that my lab simulation data proved my conjecture but I need more work by saying:

"The lab simulation shows me promising but the proof of this Theorem can not be adapted from the old proof"...

I feel wired by saying "shows me promising"... is there something wrong? How may I make it better?

Thank you!

Comment: These are possible: *It (the simulation or its result) is promising. It looks promising. It makes my conjecture look promising. It makes my conjecture worth pursuing.* and so on.

Comment: The example as given isn't grammatical (unless it's a *very* contrived context where the output from the simulation depicts me in the act of making a promise). A minimal "fix" would be to add a noun such as ***indications*** after ***promising*** (i.e. - *the indications shown by the simulation are promising/favourable/encouraging*). The word ***Theorem*** should definitely not be capitalized unless you're imitating Victorian or earlier writing styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The lab simulation shows me promising but the proof of this Theorem can not be adapted from the old proof

I think what you want to say is:

> The lab simulation **looks promising** but the proof of this theorem can not be adapted from the old proof.

We use the expression "looks promising" (or "seems promising") when we think we are on the right track, but further analysis needs to be done for confirmation. For example, here is a [quote](http://drexel.edu/cnhp/news/current/archive/2010/December/2010-12-8_BradtMusicResearch/) from a researcher at Drexel University:

> “These results look promising, but we need more trials to strengthen the evidence.”

and an [energy study](http://cordis.europa.eu/result/rcn/59049_en.html) concluded:

> The results seem promising but more tests must be done during the second period in order to confirm the first result.

---

Incidentally, there is no need to capitalize the word [*theorum*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63816/too-many-thes-here-should-i-delete-some), unless you are referring to a specific theorum by name (as in *Theorum 7.2*, e.g., or *the Pythagorean Theorem*).