# Too many "the"s here. Should I delete some?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, style

I have a sentence:

> The Theorem states the properties of the solution of the
>   model.

Too many "the" here... Is there anything wrong in grammar?

Comment: You could use fewer of-phrases and say *the model's solution*. Replacing *the* by another determiner might work as well (*this* for example).

Comment: *Grammatically*, there's nothing wrong. In principle you could extend it to ***The** theorem states **the** properties of **the** orbits of **the** planets in **the** solar system*, or construct even longer sequences. If you don't like it for stylistic reasons you can always rephrase things, but you don't *have* to. I suspect most native speakers wouldn't really notice the repetition anyway, if it were in a context where each individual article was a "reasonable" usage (for example, ***the** theorem* and ***the** model* both imply that these things have already been mentioned).

Comment: I agree with @Sander. There is nothing wrong with that sentence, but "The theorem states the properties of the model's solution" would work nicely!

Comment: I agree with the others; no cause for concern here. You're certainly not breaking any rules. If you think the sentence reads a bit awkwardly, you might be able to change the first "The" to "This", depending on the surrounding context: *This theorem states the properties of the solution of the model.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying too heavily on the phrase "of the" to attribute nouns to other nouns in terms of ownership.

You can add verbs to this sentence to help remove the "thes" if you don't like the sentence now. However, nothing is technically wrong with it. The verbs will perform the attributing for you, instead of "of."

> The Theorem states properties exhibited by the model's solution.

I don't know if "exhibited" is the right verb here. You'll have to analyze your own context to use the correct word.

You can also attribute these nouns to their owners or creators via possession to further eliminate usage of "the." For example:

> Einstein's Theorem states properties exhibited by his model's solution.

Or:

> Einstein's Theorem states the properties of his solution of the model.

Again, you'll have to analyze your own context to figure out what nouns need to be attributed to whom.

Answer (score -2):

those THEs can be replaced by any other determinants too.

Comment: *Determiner* not **determinant*.